# Error on loading Xamarin.Forms sample project

Tags: xamarin

Just playing with Xamarin.Forms, downloaded sample project TipCalc from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TipCalc). When I try to open the solution in Xamarin Studio I am getting this error.

[image]

When i try to build the project, i get this error

> Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.5\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019) (TipCalc.Android)

Please someone guide me, what should i configure in my project, to make this to run successfully. I am using Xamarin Studio 5, my OS is windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: Have you yourself changed any setting of your studio? Because, this project built well on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [Portable Library Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/) followed by Xamarin.Android to fix this. This error occurs if we try to load the pcl project without installing portable library tools, because Xamarin checks for following file in the machine while loading pcl project.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.0Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets

Comment: How did you solve this issue ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: That Guid is for Portable Class Library, I think you havn't installed pcl, download  it from the above link.